# Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Remote server has closed the connection' after Mongo 2.6 upgrade

Tags: php, mongodb

After successfully upgrading from **Mongo 2.4.10** to **Mongo 2.6.0**  (I verified that I can query the database in the shell) I got some problems with my previously working php code.

Uncaught exception `'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Remote server has closed the connection'` and also points me to the line which looks like: `$m = new Mongo();`

I am using `Php 5.5.10-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1` with `1.4.5 phpMongo Driver` (which I think has not been upgraded to support 2.6 version). Anyone experienced the same issue after 2.6 upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually everything appeared to be simpler than that (I should blame only me and not php mongo driver):

I was using [new Mongo();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.construct.php) to connect to database (which is apparently deprecated)

> Instanciating this class will emit E_DEPRECATED warning, and turn off
>   acknowledged writes.

Strangely enough I never saw this in my logs although I have `E_ALL` as my warning level. Anyway after I changed to recommended way [new MongoClient();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You always want to upgrade the driver *before* upgrading the server.

The MongoDB PHP Driver version 1.5.0 (and later) have MongoDB 2.6.0 (and later) support, where as certain things will not work when using the 1.4.x (or older) releases of the MongoDB PHP Driver.

I strongly recommend you upgrade to the 1.5.1 release of the MongoDB PHP Driver.
Furthermore, the "Mongo" object has been deprecated, you really want to use the "MongoClient" class.

That being said. This should work just fine.
What does your mongod.log say?
Can you connect to localhost:27017 using the `mongo` shell?

Comment: Actually driver was not the problem. Funny enough I found the problem exactly when you posted it (the same minute :-) ). The problem is with new Mongo() and was solved with `mongoClient`. Also the problem has been solved, thank you and +1.

Comment: $ sudo pecl upgrade mongo

Comment: This one gives me "Nothing to upgrade" and `sudo apt-get install php5-mongo` gives me `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mongo : Depends: phpapi-20090626
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: I don't know why the the php5-mongo package has broken dependencies.. Maybe "sudo apt-cache update" will fix that.. But I don't believe Ubuntu have packaged the 1.5.1 release yet

Comment: `pecl clear-cache` did not help, as for `apt-cache update` it is not a valid command. Thank you for looking into the problem.

Comment: apt-get update, sorry :) Which version do you have installed now? If pecl upgrade mongo says "Nothing to upgrade" you should have 1.5.1 installed

Comment: already tried `update`. I do not know which version do I have now (previously it was 1.4.5) because, when I heard that there is a new one out there I tried to install it with `sudo pecl install mongo` which told me that it has installed it. But right now I can not see it in my `phpinfo` (it shows nothing nonetheless `extension=mongo.so` is in `php.ini`).

Comment: Wait. What. Now you can't see it in phpinfo()? That seems very unrelated from your original problem. Maybe post a different question explaining the problem from the beginning?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. I told in the very first comment that I solved my original problem. After that I was just asking you how to update the driver. One more time sorry for this.