# GAE PHP Lose connection with mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, google-app-engine, mlab

I am building PHP app with codeigniter and using GAE with Mongodb. GAE is billing enabled but the connection to mongo is not stable and it drops 1/4 when the app is online, locally works fine with GAE PHP SDK:

## php.ini

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "libxml_disable_entity_loader"
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = “1”

extension="mongo.so"
```

## mongo_library.php

```
try {
    //connect to the mongodb server
    SELF::$mongo_client = new MongoClient($config_data['mongo_connection_string']);

    //select the mongodb database
    $this->db = SELF::$mongo_client->selectDB($config_data['mongo_database']);

} catch (MongoConnectionException $exception) {
     //if mongodb is not connect, then display the error
     show_error('Unable to connect to Database', 500);
}
```

I am using mongo free plan from mongolab.com google cloud provider. 
Here is the link where is show [My app](http://hejinterio-1033.appspot.com/main/gae) and where you can see how it fails by refreshing couple of times.

```
$a = mongo_db::$mongo_client;

$connections = $a->getConnections();

print_r($connections);
```

Comment: but this is clearly not a problem with your code. you get a connection that works and there's nothing in your code that says `on the third call to this url fail....`.

Comment: I had a quick look - appears to be an issue in the mongo client and how it recycles socket descriptors.  Would it be possible for you to file a bug in our issue tracker? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3

Comment: There is a high probability that GAE is using an older "mongo.so" driver extension, which is known to have similar connection drop issues with newer MongoDB servers.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947873/failed-to-connect-to-localhost27017-remote-server-has-closed-the-connection

Comment: Also the 2nd answer from the link does not pertain to your code, since you are already using new MongoClient, so the 1st answer I think is related to the same issue that you are experiencing

Comment: Hi , I have Lumen project i want to host on App Enginge and want to connect it with mongolab. I cant find solution says that Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found . Can you please guide me how to install it ?

Comment: @victor Add php.ini in the same directory where is app.yaml and write
for windows: `extension="php_mongo.dll"` for linux: `extension="mongo.so"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue I opened:

```
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12392
```

and this issue/bug is already fixed.